# Paste special method of Range class failed - error 104

Tags: vba, excel

Hopefully this should be straight forward but I can't see what I have missed. I am getting the runtime error on the Paste Special line just after clearing the contents of Column A on the "original" sheet. Can someone please help me?

```
 Sub BACSConversion2()

 Dim MyNewBook As String
 Dim MySaveFile As String
 Dim fileToOpen As Variant
 Dim fileName As String
 Dim sheetName As String

 'Turn off display alerts
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 'Turn off screen updates
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 'This calls the routine to get the text file data
 'Call CopyTxtFile

 'Opens the folder to location to select txt file
 fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
 If fileToOpen <> False Then

    Workbooks.OpenText fileName:=fileToOpen, _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
 End If
 'Creates the file name based on txt file name
 fileName = Mid(fileToOpen, InStrRev(fileToOpen, "\") + 1)
 'Creates the sheet name based on the active txt file
 sheetName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4)

 'Save active file as...
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\Accounts (New)\Management Information 
 (Analysis)\Phil Hanmore - Analysis\Neil Test\Test Destination Folder\" & 
 fileName & ".CSV")

 'Selects all data in column A and copies to clipboard
 Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select
 Selection.Copy
 'Closes the workbook
 'ActiveWorkbook.Close

 'Open the original document where the BACS file is located
 Workbooks.Open "S:\Accounts (New)\Management Information (Analysis)\Phil 
  Hanmore - Analysis\Neil Test\copy of bacs conversation calc.xlsx"
 'Selects the worksheet called "Original"
 Sheets("Original").Select

 Range("A:A").ClearContents


 'Paste selected values from previous sheet
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


 'Selects appropriate worksheet - Non-MyPayFINAL
 Sheets("Non-MyPay FINAL").Select

 'Selects all data in column A and copies to clipboard
 Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select
  Selection.Copy

 'Add a new workbook
 Workbooks.Add
 'Paste selected values from previous sheet
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

 'Build SaveAs file name
    MySaveFile = Format(Now(), "DDMMYYYY") & "NonMyPayFINAL" & ".CSV"
    'Save template file as...
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\Accounts (New)\Management Information 
  (Analysis)\Phil Hanmore - Analysis\Neil Test\" & MySaveFile)
    'Close the new saved file
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

 'Selects appropriate worksheet - MyPayFINAL
 Sheets("MyPay FINAL").Select

 'Selects all data in column A and copies to clipboard
 Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select
 Selection.Copy

 'Add a new workbook
 Workbooks.Add
 'Paste selected values from previous sheet
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

 'Build SaveAs file name
    MySaveFile = Format(Now(), "DDMMYYYY") & "MyPayFINAL" & ".CSV"
    'Save template file as...
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\Accounts (New)\Management Information 
  (Analysis)\Phil Hanmore - Analysis\Neil Test\" & MySaveFile)
    'Close the new saved file
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
 'Close original source workbook
  Workbooks("bacs conversation calc").Close

 'Turn on display alerts
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 'Turn on screen updates
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

Comment: Change the order which is currently clearing the clipboard. Clear the contents and then copy and paste. Btw you don't need to Select `Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Copy`.

Comment: @SJR Thank you for the quick reply, would you be able to give me an example per chance?

Comment: After I clear the contents, do I need to switch back to the CSV file, copy, return to the "Original" sheet and then paste?

Comment: See suggested code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code actually assigns the copy range to a variable and uses that. Because you are using various workbooks and sheets it would be good practice to assign variables to them and refer to them directly so that there is no doubt about which file you are referencing. I'm not 100% sure what you are doing so have not done that.

```
Sub BACSConversion2()

Dim MyNewBook As String
Dim MySaveFile As String
Dim fileToOpen As Variant
Dim fileName As String
Dim sheetName As String
Dim rCopy As Range

'Turn off display alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Turn off screen updates
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'This calls the routine to get the text file data
'Call CopyTxtFile

'Opens the folder to location to select txt file
fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
If fileToOpen <> False Then
    Workbooks.OpenText fileName:=fileToOpen, _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
End If
'Creates the file name based on txt file name
fileName = Mid(fileToOpen, InStrRev(fileToOpen, "\") + 1)
'Creates the sheet name based on the active txt file
sheetName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4)

'Save active file as...
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\Accounts (New)\Management Information (Analysis)\Phil Hanmore - Analysis\Neil Test\Test Destination Folder\" & _
fileName & ".CSV")

'Selects all data in column A and copies to clipboard
Set rCopy = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
'Closes the workbook
'ActiveWorkbook.Close

'Open the original document where the BACS file is located
Workbooks.Open "S:\Accounts (New)\Management Information (Analysis)\Phil Hanmore - Analysis\Neil Test\copy of bacs conversation calc.xlsx"
'Selects the worksheet called "Original"
Sheets("Original").Range("A:A").ClearContents

'Paste selected values from previous sheet
rCopy.Copy
Sheets("Original").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Selects appropriate worksheet - Non-MyPayFINAL
Sheets("Non-MyPay FINAL").Select

'Selects all data in column A and copies to clipboard
Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy

'Add a new workbook
Workbooks.Add
'Paste selected values from previous sheet
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Build SaveAs file name
MySaveFile = Format(Now(), "DDMMYYYY") & "NonMyPayFINAL" & ".CSV"
'Save template file as...
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\Accounts (New)\Management Information (Analysis)\Phil Hanmore - Analysis\Neil Test\" & MySaveFile)
'Close the new saved file
ActiveWorkbook.Close

'Selects appropriate worksheet - MyPayFINAL
Sheets("MyPay FINAL").Select

'Selects all data in column A and copies to clipboard
Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy

'Add a new workbook
Workbooks.Add
'Paste selected values from previous sheet
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Build SaveAs file name
MySaveFile = Format(Now(), "DDMMYYYY") & "MyPayFINAL" & ".CSV"
'Save template file as...
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\Accounts (New)\Management Information (Analysis)\Phil Hanmore - Analysis\Neil Test\" & MySaveFile)
'Close the new saved file
ActiveWorkbook.Close
'Close original source workbook
Workbooks("bacs conversation calc").Close

'Turn on display alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'Turn on screen updates
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, works like a charm and I can now see the mistake that I made. I really appreciate your help :)